# How to integrate PayUMoney with AngularJS-1.6.4

Tags: angularjs, payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayUMoney with my Angularjs 1.6 App but it show
**Corrective Action
Please note that this is PayU's Test Environment - https://test.payu.in/_payment , but the key (********) you are using is not a Test Environment key.**

I don't know what i did wrong.
Suggest me a proper solution for test environment of PayUMoney with AngularJS-1.6

Comment: same key and salt working on Php but not working in AngularJS-1.6

Comment: If you are using form tag, then check if you are passing your merchant key value in that so your test key is dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply yes i am using form tag and i have passed my merchant key in that and i have switched my payumoney account to test mode but still same problem occoured.

Comment: Created a sample with angular 1. Please check if it helps - https://www.devglan.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-payumoney-integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my working code. Wrote 2 days back only..Its on Angular 2... Check whether you are passing the parameters right.

```
<form ngNoForm cl  action="https://test.payu.in/_payment" method="POST" style="display:none">
  <input type="text" name="key" [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.key" />
  <input  type="text" name="txnid" [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.txnid"/>
  <input type ="text" name="amount"  [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.amount"/>
  <input type="text" name="currency" value="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.currency" />
  <input  type="text" name="productinfo" [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.productinfo" />
  <input type ="text" name="firstname"  [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.firstname"/>
  <input type="text" name="email" [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.email" />
  <input type ="text" name="phone"  [value]="paymentInfo.hash_sequence.mobile"/>
  <input type ="text" name="hash"  [value]="paymentInfo.hash"/>  
  <input type ="text" name="surl"  value="{{environment.api}}/payment/success"/>
  <input type ="text" name="furl"  value="{{environment.api}}/payment/failure"/>
  <input type ="text" name="curl"  value="{{environment.api}}/payment/cancel"/>
  <button id="get_payment" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

if still the problem persists, quick hack will be make some error in hash and check whether you are getting the has error message. If you get hash error message, then your code is fine.. You need to figure out where your key is getting overriden.

The best way is make your form visible and visually see the data.